# Input Mismatch when reading text file

Tags: java

I have a file with data organized like so:

```
Circle 156 1 1 10
Square 237 1 3 2
Triangle 212 3 3 3 4
```

In a while loop, I am storing each data piece from one line into their own separate variables and then I print those variables as so:

```
Shape: Circle ID: 156 Point (1,1) Radius: 10
Shape: Square ID: 237 Point (1,3) Side Length: 2
Shape: Triangle ID: 232 Point (3,3) Height: 3 Base: 4
```

I wrote this while loop, but it runs it immediately returns an Input Mismatch Exception where it reads the first Int:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
            String name = input.next();
            int id = input.nextInt(); // Where the error occurs
            int num1 = input.nextInt();
            int num2 = input.nextInt();
            if (name == "Circle") {
                int radius = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("Shape: %s ID: %d Point: (%d, %d) Radius: %d\n" , name, id, num1, num2, radius);
            } else if (name == "Square") {
                int length = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("Shape: %s ID: %d Point: (%d, %d) Side Length: %d\n" , name, id, num1, num2, length);
            } else if (name == "Triangle") {
                int height = input.nextInt();
                int base = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("Shape: %s ID: %d Point: (%d, %d) Height: %d Base %d\n" , name, id, num1, num2, height, base);
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure how to fix my code from here.

Comment: Use equals to compare strings not ==

Comment: Wow that was the error. That was so simple how did I not think of that? Anyway, thank you so much! I was literally stuck on this issue!